# What is the label order in nodes with multiple labels?

Tags: neo4j

I have a node with multiple labels `(node:one:two:three)` . When i choose the color for this node I want it to be in `:one`color (which is red). But it only gives me the `:three`color. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neo4j Browser stores the node label colors in a "Graph Style Sheet", and it is the order of the node labels in that file that determines the color used. The color used is the one for the **last** applicable label in that file.

Click on the star in the Browser's left panel, and then click the "Graph Style Sheet" button. It will display the stylesheet in a window that has an icon on top that allows you to export to a file. You can edit the file so that the `node.one` entry is last in the file, and that should give you the color you want for that node. Drop the edited file to the special line at the bottom of the Graph Style Sheet window to import it back into the Browser.

Comment: The GRASS is cascading, i.e. it goes from top to bottom like regular CSS if multiple selectors match.